# deserialize empty String to a List<string>

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've implemented a method returns a `List<string>` according to an json string.

It's working well up to I've realized that I'm trying to deserialize an empty string. It doesn't crash neither raises an exception. It returns a `null` value instead an empty `List<string>`.

The question is, what could I touch in order to returns me an empty `List<string>` instead a `null` value?

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content, typeof(List<string>));
```

**EDIT**
Generic method:

```
public object Deserialize(string content, Type type) {
    if (type.GetType() == typeof(Object))
        return (Object)content;
    if (type.Equals(typeof(String)))
        return content;

    try
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content, type);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ApiException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: `type.GetType()` is wrong; it will give some concrete type inheriting from `System.Type` which is not what you want. You want `if (type == typeof(Object))` there. In the next `if` you can use `==` as well (for consistency).

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using the [`null coalescing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator (`??`):

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content, typeof(List<string>)) ?? new List<string>();
```

You could also do it by setting the `NullValueHandling` to `NullValueHandling.Ignore` like this:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(string content)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    { 
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore    
    };

    try
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content, settings);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        throw new ApiException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there any shortcut which stands for that out of the box?

Comment: Thanks Simon! Let me ask you for solving this problem in a generic form (I've edited my post). As you can figure out, I'm using one method in order to deserialize whichever json string I receive. So the specific `typeof(List<string>)` is whichever type C# let me. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content, type)`